# The console double prints a line im not sure why

Tags: java

i have a for loop with if statements and it always prints the first and then the second one right after

```
for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
                if(headers[i] == true) {
                    if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[0]) {
                        System.out.println("\nType a valid date in the format M/DD/YYYY");
                        date = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[1]) {
                        System.out.println("\nType a valid state. Please print out the full name");
                        state = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[2]) {
                        System.out.println("\nPlease select a race ");
                        race = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[3]) {
                        System.out.println("\nType an average income");
                        medIncome = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[4]) {
                        System.out.println("\nType the % Bachelor's Degree or Higher");
                        bachDegree = scan.nextLine();
                        
                    }
                    else if(headOpt[i] == headOpt[5]) {
                        System.out.println("\nType the Clinton margin of improvement");
                        clintImprov = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("\nType  the dem margin of improvement");
                        marginImprov = scan.nextLine();
                    }
                }
            }
```

i need it to print one at a time. for example i ask a question and it waits for an input

Comment: What's `headOpt`? Also, is there some `nextInt()`, `next()` or similare before the loop?

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use each option once, why are you using an equals check instead of just checking the value of i? If your array headOpt[] has equal values, it'll enter the if statement on that value.

This should probably be better. Intuitively I want to remove the items that are supposed to only execute once and put them in a sequential code, but it's hard to do so without knowing your code while still respecting headers.length. You can also write it as a switch statement for clarity.

```
for(i=0;i<headers.length;i++) {
            if(headers[i] == true) {
                if(i == 0) {
                    System.out.println("\nType a valid date in the format M/DD/YYYY");
                    date = scan.nextLine();
                }
                else if(i == 1) {
                    System.out.println("\nType a valid state. Please print out the full name");
                    state = scan.nextLine();
                }
                else if(i == 2) {
                    System.out.println("\nPlease select a race ");
                    race = scan.nextLine();
                }
                else if(i == 3) {
                    System.out.println("\nType an average income");
                    medIncome = scan.nextLine();
                }
                else if(i == 4) {
                    System.out.println("\nType the % Bachelor's Degree or Higher");
                    bachDegree = scan.nextLine();
                    
                }
                else if(i == 5) {
                    System.out.println("\nType the Clinton margin of improvement");
                    clintImprov = scan.nextLine();
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("\nType  the dem margin of improvement");
                    marginImprov = scan.nextLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping `headers` and according to your problem statement more than one message is being displayed. Which strongly suggests that `headers[i]` is not properly set to `false` once its corresponding value has successfully loaded. You will also need to check for the value of `i` rather than comparing it to other stuff:

```
for (i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    if (headers[i]) { //assuming it's boolean
        switch (i) {
            case 0 {
                /* Some logic here */
            } break;
            case 1 {
                /* Some logic here */
            } break;
            case 2 {
                /* Some logic here */
            } break;
            headers[i] = false; // Making sure that we are not asking later for the same thing again
        }
    }
}
```

I do not open the next `headers` element here by setting it to true because you might be setting it to true somewhere else. If this is not enough for a solution for you, then you might want to provide us more information.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recommendation.

Reduce the *if-else* code by using a *method*.

```java
static String in(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    return scan.nextLine();
}
```

And, re-name *headOpt*.

```java
if(h[i] == h[0]) date = in("\nType a valid date in the format M/DD/YYYY");
else if(h[i] == h[1]) state = in("\nType a valid state. Please print out the full name");
else if(h[i] == h[2]) race = in("\nPlease select a race ");
else if(h[i] == h[3]) medIncome = in("\nType an average income");
else if(h[i] == h[4]) bachDegree = in("\nType the % Bachelor's Degree or Higher");
else if(h[i] == h[5]) clintImprov = in("\nType the Clinton margin of improvement");
else marginImprov = in("\nType  the dem margin of improvement");
```

Or, utilize a *[Map](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html)*.

```java
Map<String, String> m = new HashMap<>() {{
    put("date", "\nType a valid date in the format M/DD/YYYY");
    put("state", "\nType a valid state. Please print out the full name");
    put("race", "\nPlease select a race ");
    put("medIncome", "\nType an average income");
    put("bachDegree", "\nType the % Bachelor's Degree or Higher");
    put("clintImprov", "\nType the Clinton margin of improvement");
    put("marginImprov", "\nType  the dem margin of improvement");
}};
```

```java
String s = in(m.get("date"));
```